# React native tone generator example

Tags: react-native, audio, tone-generator

I am new to react-native, i am trying to integrate library of from npm but could not find proper example. I want to generate tone for both android and iOS platform in react native using frequency,volume, duration.

Comment: Could you please elaborate where are you facing the problem?Do you have issues in using npm to install any dependency or you have any other problem.

Comment: I am developing for android. I have installed react-native-tone-android and tried to call Tone.play(4000,50) but no sound generated.

Comment: I am trying this https://github.com/perotta/react-native-tone-android